# How to setup a very basic request response HTTP server in Racket?

Tags: http, get, racket

The official Racket Docs go into too much detail with specific string processing, so I'm struggling. What would be the easiest way to set up a basic web server that accepts a HTTP GET Request and returns HTML in Racket? Preferably with #lang web-server/insta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial [Continue: Web Applications in Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/index.html) has an example of how to do this at the very beginning (Section 1, Getting Started).

Long story short, type the following into DrRacket and hit run. (And hit stop to kill the server). Hopefully that helps you get started.

```
#lang web-server/insta
(define (start request)
  (response/xexpr
   '(html
     (head (title "My Blog"))
     (body (h1 "Under construction")))))
```

Comment: Did you omit something by accident?

Comment: I was more interested in processing a get request say page/?paramater=something

Comment: Oh, okay. In that case you probably want something like get-pure-port/headers and post-pure-port/headers: http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/url.html?q=get-pure-port#%28def._%28%28lib._net%2Furl..rkt%29._get-pure-port%2Fheaders%29%29 (or just get-pure-port if you don't care about the headers.)